# Is there any upsides to filing one's Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization) via mail instead of online?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

I read https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/reports/SIGNED-Section-4103-FY2021-Report-9-7-21.pdf ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220415173821/https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/reports/SIGNED-Section-4103-FY2021-Report-9-7-21.pdf)):

> For example, in FY 2020 approximately 49 percent of applicants
> choose to file their N-400, Application for Naturalization, online and 51 percent continue to file
> the paper form via mail.

Is there any upsides to filing one's Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization) via mail instead of online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://qr.ae/pv2Jov, one upside to filing one's Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization) via mail instead of online is that it avoids issues in the online filing system for Form N-400.

Quote from [Cynthia-Rosenberg](https://www.quora.com/profile/Cynthia-Rosenberg):

> My law firm NEVER files these online anymore The system is not reliable and has too many problems which we discovered at the interview for those we filed online. Also do not trust the client account system.